# Socket.IO Client .NET example for xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, node.js, xamarin

I'm looking for Socket.IO Client .NET example for xamarin android I have a chat site using node.js and I want to make a chat android application for it so I'm looking for any example to use Socket.io with android C# xamarin i tried this Component but i didn't understand anything

Socket.io For xamarin

Or may it not work for some reason

So please if there any example or tutorial to use it

Comment: Have you looked at this one? https://components.xamarin.com/view/socketioclientdotnet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you've installed the [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/) package, then for tutorial and example for this package, you can always refer to its source project on Github.

It is said in its "README.md":

> More examples can be found in [unit tests](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/blob/master/Src/SocketIoClientDotNet.Tests.net45/ClientTests/ServerConnectionTest.cs) acting against the test [server](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet/tree/master/TestServer).

You can see the code example for this plugin and the server is also included in this package source, I think it should be clear to help us get started.

And since you didn't post any code, we can't figure out why your code doesn't work, next time when you ask question like why it doesn't work, maybe you can share us your code.

Answer (score 0):

That will not work as this package is not supported on Mono.Android or Mono.Touch
.